# How To Create Custom CSS Theme For Google no CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA

Tags: recaptcha

I tried to make any customization to Google no CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA and failed.

The main thing that I want to do is to change its width, height, and color.

Can any one help me please.

Comment: Do you want us to never ask anything? Because you don't like it?!

Comment: Or because you don't know it?

Comment: We just trying to learn, we don't fight here

Comment: I have the same question, it looks iframed at 304px wide. Wanted to change the width...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noCaptcha reCaptcha client code is an iframe.

You can just choose between dark and light Google provided themes.

**UPDATE**: You cannot modify the content inside an iframe, unless it's the same domain. Some services let you pass parameters in the url query, but this is not the case.

Comment: If anyone try to apply css to an iframe please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe).

Comment: Thanks @Engt.MTH ,  updated the answer to explaing why the iframe is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem with google new captcha but this trick worked fine for me.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="light" id="google-captcha" data-sitekey="yoursecretkey" style="transform:scale(0.77);-webkit-transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;"></div>
```

You can also check this [link](https://www.geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/) for more information. I hope this will help some one.